# Type Orm get the latest entry on each catagory

Tags: sql, typescript, typeorm

This is my entity.

```js
@Entity({ name: 'documents' })
export class UserDocument extends TenantBaseModel {
    @Column({ nullable: false })
    user_id?: number;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    name: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    type?: UserDocumentType;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    s3_link?: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    attachment_extension?: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    attachment_size?: number;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.name = '';
        this.s3_link = '';
        this.attachment_extension = '';
        this.attachment_size = 0;
    }
}
```

And this is my return json which is getting generated after calling this particular.

```json
{
   "statusCode":200,
   "requestId":"35a26c53-9fdc-4f53-b49a-161a39b144d4",
   "data":[
      {
         "id":3,
         "tenant_id":1,
         "name":"PAN",
         "s3_link":"",
         "attachment_extension":"jpg",
         "attachment_size":1000,
         "created_at":"2020-09-30T06:21:51.596Z",
         "user_id":21,
         "type":"PERSONAL DOCUMENTS"
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "tenant_id":1,
         "name":"PAN",
         "s3_link":"",
         "attachment_extension":"jpg",
         "attachment_size":1000,
         "created_at":"2020-09-30T06:21:51.614Z",
         "user_id":21,
         "type":"PERSONAL DOCUMENTS"
      },
      {
         "id":244,
         "tenant_id":0,
         "name":"VISITING CARD",
         "s3_link":"",
         "attachment_extension":"jpg",
         "attachment_size":25986,
         "created_at":"2021-11-18T05:03:29.079Z",
         "user_id":21,
         "type":"EMPLOYEE DOCUMENTS"
      },
      {
         "id":245,
         "tenant_id":0,
         "name":"VISITING CARD",
         "s3_link":"",
         "attachment_extension":"jpg",
         "attachment_size":25986,
         "created_at":"2021-11-18T05:05:12.098Z",
         "user_id":21,
         "type":"PERSONAL DOCUMENTS"
      },
      {
         "id":246,
         "tenant_id":0,
         "name":"VISITING CARD",
         "s3_link":"",
         "attachment_extension":"jpg",
         "attachment_size":25986,
         "created_at":"2021-11-18T05:05:52.682Z",
         "user_id":21,
         "type":"EDUCATIONAL DOCUMENTS"
      }
   ]
}
```

What is the query which i have to build to get the latest entry in a particular type using type orm for example on the above json we could see that the type `PERSONAL DOCUMENT` has three entries but the time stamp for all three are different i just need the lates `PERSONAL DOCUMENT` with latest time stamp same goes for other entries as well such as `EDUCATIONAL DOCUMENTS`,`EMPLOYEE DOCUMENT` accordingly. My question is is that possible to build a query in typeorm only if so how?